# GDB: automatically flatten structures when printing / dumping to file

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a complex C structure that contains numerous pointers to more complex structures.

While debugging with GDB I want to be able to flatten the structure to the screen / file.

Indeed, I can write a very long pretty printer function, but as all the pointers are with known types (no void pointers) and GDB already knows how to do so with manually calling p *x, can it be used to achieve this?

Usually GDB prints the first level of the structure without recursively entering other levels.

Answer (score 2):

> Usually GDB prints the first level of the structure without recursively entering other levels.

If GDB didn't do this, what would happen when you try to print a circular linked list?

Generally, writing a pretty-print function inside your program is a good idea anyway: a day will come when you'll have a non-debug executable, the "root" of your structure in a register, and you'll need to examine the structure.

But if you don't want to do that, a generic "follow all pointers" pretty printer can easily be written in [Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html). Just be careful to never call such a printer on a graph with cycles.